# Do enhancements count as magic when it comes to magic immunity?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, magic, immunities

I was looking at a construct's immunities and noticed "immune to magic" in its list. Naturally, this means you can't really cast spells at it. How does this affect magical weapons? Do Enhancement bonuses have no effect when attacking these creatures? Do weapon special abilities like flaming and frost not do damage to it? Furthermore, would an alchemist's bombs damage the creature at all? Since they explode using the alchemist's own magical powers.

Comment: Welcome to RPG.SE! Take the [tour] if you haven't already, and check out the [help] for more guidance.

Comment: I cleaned up some of your language (in the case the other question doesn't clear up your concerns) to reflect that Enchantment is a school of magic, while weapons are magically Enhanced. Yes, basically everyone knows what you're talking about, but I like to ensure that we're using appropriate game terms where they exist.

Comment: You seem to have a secondary question at the end that might stand on its own, as the duplicate does not address it. If you edit your question to focus on that, it might get reopened. (Also, you can post as many questions as you have, but we ask that you stick to one per post for clarity.)

Comment: If you remove the bit about enchanted weapons, and cut the question down to being about other affects like the *Alchemists Bombs* feature, we should be able to remove the *Duplicate* flag and get you an answer.